# Is there a Platform-independent Web-based replacement for Word Templates?

Tags: ms-word

The above Title is my Manager's words, not mine. :)

This is a follow-up to a [question that I posted previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963467/converting-ms-word-2002-templates-from-pc-to-mac). After reading my assessment on the impacts of converting Word Templates from PC to Mac, I have now been asked to investigate whether Word Templates can be replaced with a "Platform-independent Web-based solution" (her words, not mine). She has suggested using Adobe Forms (ie. Adobe Designer).

Personally, I think the only truly platform-independent web-based solution is text files or html forms. What do other people think?

Comment: Is this one really programming-related?  If so, you might want to emphasis that part of it more.

Comment: It appears as though the project I'm working on is progressing more towards the non-programming side of things. Apologies for not posting this question at Super User instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's called WordprocessingML (aka. WordXML, WordML)...**

- *Overview of WordprocessingML [Word 2003 XML Reference]* at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa212812(office.11).aspx.
- MSDN Search for "WordML" at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=WordML&ac=3

**It could be called XForms...**

The Web was suppose to be platform-independent electronic documents. In other words, if you truly want platform-independence, then I agree with you and your forms should be in HTML. Yet, HTML forms are really not a good development platform. That is why Adobe, Microsoft, and others provide "form" solutions. XForms is an attempt to make developing and using HTML forms more flexible, overcome its limitations, and provide a platform-independent object model for completing HTML forms. You might want to look at XForms at http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/Forms/.

**But, I wouldn't call it PDF**

In my opinion, working with PDF files is difficult. I have not looked at the file format specification, but I heard it is not trivial. Moreover, you need a custom editor and you are locked into one vendor, which is Adobe. (Yet, there are other open-source and vendors who support the file format.) Adobe is not know for creating programs that are easy to use.

**My Suggestion**

If you are already using Word, then moving to WordML should be fairly easy. You can easily convert your existing Word documents into WordML by simply saving them as XML from the Save Dialog; therefore, you can automate this process through code. In addition, I believe WordML supports form templates (the actual form) and data documents (the actual data for a form).

Comment: Depending on the scope of your problem, CSS or WordML.

Comment: WordML includes a way of binding a content control to XML (like XForms), but leaves out the form bit (possibly because in their view that's InfoPath).  Of course, you can add the forms part yourself :-)

Answer (score 0):

**It's called PDF...**

At the core (and without the million of extra unnecessary features" that's exactly the niche that Adobe PDFs were designed to fill.

I'd suggest you look more into Adobe Acrobat Professional for more info. Although, I don't think there's any good way to directly convert Word docs to PDF format.

*Note: This question should be moved to Super User since it's not **really** programming related*

Answer (score 0):

[Google Docs](http://docs.google.com/) meets those requirements of a *Platform-independent Web-based solution*. Your mileage will vary with Google Docs though - if you just want to use it for letters, it's good. Much beyond that, it's rather limited. Unless you get the Premier (read: Corporate) version which you have to pay for, you won't be able to programmatically fiddle with the templates.

If you want a "Platform-independent solution", go with ODF or OOXML. You can make either "web-based" to your hearts content - maybe with HTML5 or another solution such as Flash or Silverlight.